# Merge two JavaScript objects into a meaningful one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two JavaScript objects:

```
var json1 = {
    "id": 12123,
    "category": "mobile",
    "title": "Iphone 6 64GB",
    "price": 99999,
    "quantity": 3
};

var json2 = {
    "id": 78652,
    "category": "mobile",
    "title": "Apple Iphone 6",
    "price": 90000,
    "quantity": 4
};
```

I want to merge these two objects into one meaningful one like this:

```
json3 = {
    "category": "mobile",
    "title": "Apple Iphone 6 64GB",
    "details": [
        {
            "json1": [
                {
                    "id": 12123,
                    "price": "99999",
                    "quantity": 3
                }
            ],
            "json2": [
                {
                    "id": 78652,
                    "price": "90000",
                    "quantity": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: title are different in both

Comment: What is the rule for merging title?

Comment: The problem im facing is using this response Im getting two Iphone object, whereas I want to display only one , and in opening of that one, Il get that two objects

Comment: json3["details"].push(json1); same with json2

Comment: Jonas, push will push the object to other, You are not getting my question, here category are same and title is also nearly same, so thats why I moved it into single object

Comment: Consider this two objects as response from two affliate apis, eg amazon and ebay, what i want is on my site, there will only iphone 6 displayed, and when i click on iphone 6 it will show my two json objects corresponding to iphone 6